# Android Download Service

Tags: android, service

Does anyone have a good example of using a service to download a file?

I am not sure whether to use remote or local and even if I was sure, I need a basic example to start with.

Basically, I want to start the service with the url of the file to downland and when the download is done end the service.

Google's example of services is filled with junk so I am not sure what is needed and what is not.

Your help is greatly appreciated.